# rosdep error while I try to install ROS on OS X 10.8

Tags: rosdep, ros-hydro, rosgraph, macosx, roslisp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to install ROS Hydro on OS X 10.8. I am strictly following the tutorial to install ROS through homebrew. I am on xcode 5.0.2 now. I am working behind a proxy. After I tap the formulae, I setup the environment with the following commands.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
$ source ~/.bash_profile

$ mkdir -p ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
$ echo "$(brew --prefix)/lib/python2.7/site-packages" >> ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```

Installed pip and successfully ran the following as well :

```
sudo pip install -U wstool rosdep rosinstall rosinstall_generator rospkg catkin-pkg Distribute sphinx
```

Successfully initialized rosdep, created the workspace and populated it with packages with the following :

```
$ rosinstall_generator desktop_full --rosdistro hydro --deps --wet-only --tar > hydro-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall
$ wstool init -j8 src hydro-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall
```

Everything went fine till here as far as i know.

Next when I need execute this :

```
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y
```

I get the following error :

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
smach_ros: No definition of [python-mock] for OS [osx]
rospack: No definition of [python-coverage] for OS [osx]
roslisp: No definition of [python-coverage] for OS [osx]
rosgraph: No definition of [python-mock] for OS [osx]
```

I am not really sure on how to handle this. Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/153156/rosdep-error-while-i-try-to-install-ros-on-os-x-10.8/) by [karthik_ms](https://answers.ros.org/users/10391/karthik_ms/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2014-04-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recent updates seem to have added those dependecies, but their rosdep definition was not added yet for OS X. I filed a pull request https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/3873

In the meantime, you can work around this by manually installing the dependecies and telling rosdep to ignore them:

```
sudo pip install -U python-mock python-coverage
rosdep install -s --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y --skip-keys "python-mock python-coverage"
```

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1